# Tesseract 3.05.00dev training tools missing

Tags: linux, c++11, ocr, tesseract, training-data

I've been trying to build the training tools for Tesseract, but still can not success.

I already installed the 3 dependencies mentioned at https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Training-Tesseract#additional-libraries-required

*libicu-52.1 libpango-1.6  libcairo-1.14.6*

I also built *Leptonica-1.73* in the same machine.
All the native libraries are already added to **$LD_LIBRARY_PATH** and binaries to **$PATH**.
I am using **gcc 4.8.4** whic meets c++11 needed standards.

Standing at root source of Tesseract, after running **./configure --prefix=path/to/tesseract** I am still getting the message:

> **You can not build training tools because of missing dependency.**

This is the configure output:

```
checking for g++... g++
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
fatal: Not a git repository: './.git'
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking --enable-graphics argument... yes
checking whether to disable cube... no
checking --enable-embedded argument... no
checking for  option to support OpenMP... -fopenmp
checking --enable-opencl argument... no
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking CL/cl.h usability... no
checking CL/cl.h presence... no
checking for CL/cl.h... no
checking OpenCL/cl.h usability... no
checking OpenCL/cl.h presence... no
checking for OpenCL/cl.h... no
checking tiffio.h usability... yes
checking tiffio.h presence... yes
checking for tiffio.h... yes
checking for clGetPlatformIDs in -lOpenCL... no
checking --enable-visibility argument... no
checking --enable-multiple-libraries argument... no
checking whether to use tessdata-prefix... yes
checking whether to enable debugging... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1966080
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ar... ar
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking if compiling with clang... no
checking whether compiler supports C++11... yes
checking for snprintf... yes
checking for library containing sem_init... -lpthread
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking sys/ipc.h usability... yes
checking sys/ipc.h presence... yes
checking for sys/ipc.h... yes
checking sys/shm.h usability... yes
checking sys/shm.h presence... yes
checking for sys/shm.h... yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking malloc.h usability... yes
checking malloc.h presence... yes
checking for malloc.h... yes
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... yes
checking for _Bool... no
checking whether #! works in shell scripts... yes
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking for getline... yes
checking for wchar_t... yes
checking for long long int... yes
checking for off_t... yes
checking for mbstate_t... yes
checking for leptonica... yes
checking for l_generateCIDataForPdf in -llept... yes
checking leptonica headers version >= 1.71... yes
checking unicode/uchar.h usability... yes
checking unicode/uchar.h presence... yes
checking for unicode/uchar.h... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for pango... yes
checking for cairo... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating tesseract.pc
config.status: creating api/Makefile
config.status: creating ccmain/Makefile
config.status: creating opencl/Makefile
config.status: creating ccstruct/Makefile
config.status: creating ccutil/Makefile
config.status: creating classify/Makefile
config.status: creating cube/Makefile
config.status: creating cutil/Makefile
config.status: creating dict/Makefile
config.status: creating neural_networks/runtime/Makefile
config.status: creating textord/Makefile
config.status: creating viewer/Makefile
config.status: creating wordrec/Makefile
config.status: creating tessdata/Makefile
config.status: creating tessdata/configs/Makefile
config.status: creating tessdata/tessconfigs/Makefile
config.status: creating testing/Makefile
config.status: creating java/Makefile
config.status: creating java/com/Makefile
config.status: creating java/com/google/Makefile
config.status: creating java/com/google/scrollview/Makefile
config.status: creating java/com/google/scrollview/events/Makefile
config.status: creating java/com/google/scrollview/ui/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating config_auto.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
```

Does any one can help me with this? I am stocked at this point.
Thank you so much!